# What does the Hausdorff-Young inequality tell us?

Tags: mathematical-physics, fourier-transform, mathematics

The [Hausdorff-Young Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff%E2%80%93Young_inequality) relates the size of a function and its Fourier coefficients.   What is meant the by "the size of a function"?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: I agree with Qmechanic. Furthermore, the wikipedia page refer to literally tells you what "size" means, it's the $L^p$-norm.

Comment: I asked in mathematics but no answer yet. I read wikipedia article but still not understanding.

Comment: That is because they probably don't recognize the rogue specific 3 in the exponents, which entered the article peremptorily on June 22 of this year, as you may ascertain. If you discussed the issue, there, you might engage more minds. You probably "shouldn't" understand the 3 bunk having special pertinence to size.

Comment: @Qmechanic I think it is an interesting question for this site; for $p=2$ we have Rayleigh's energy theorem (Parseval's theorem), and it has a clear physical meaning used daily by every spectrum analyzer. Maybe the Hausdorff-Young inequality for $p\ne 2$ has also physical meaning, does it?

Comment: I'd urge you to withdraw your question in favor of the MSE one. But since you asked about sizes, think of this as an extreme extension of the [Plancherel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem) comparing average lengths of vectors in coordinate and Fourier spaces.